# Mysql query to get records from different columns for the id

Tags: mysql, join

Following is the details for my table structure.

Table structure "departments":

```
id  |   department
1   |   Department 1
2   |   Department 2
3   |   Department 3
4   |   Department 4
```

Table structure "custom_forms_departments":

```
id  |   form_id | department_id | enduser_to_department | department_to_enduser
1   |   5       |   1           |       Y               |       N
2   |   6       |   1           |       N               |       Y
3   |   8       |   2           |       Y               |       Y
4   |   7       |   3           |       N               |       Y
5   |   4       |   3           |       Y               |       N
6   |   2       |   4           |       N               |       N
```

Result should be return department_id which have the vaue "Y" for field "enduser_to_department" and "department_to_enduser" in same row or in different row.

department_id = 1 contatin value "Y" for "enduser_to_department" and "department_to_enduser" in different rows
department_id = 2 contatin value "Y" for "enduser_to_department" and "department_to_enduser" in same rows
department_id = 3 contatin value "Y" for "enduser_to_department" and "department_to_enduser" in different rows

Result:

```
  department_id | departments
    1           |   Department 1
    2           |   Department 2
    3           |   Deapartment 3
```

I am using following SQL query which is not giving proper result.

```
SELECT departments.department_id, departments.department 
FROM custom_forms_departments , departments
WHERE departments.department_id = custom_forms_departments.department_id
AND (custom_forms_departments.enduser_to_department = 'Y'
OR  custom_forms_departments.department_to_enduser = 'Y')
GROUP BY departments.department_id 
ORDER BY departments.department_id DESC
```

Please suggest me for this one.

Comment: you might want to make some sort of attempt at formatting that in a more eyeball pleasing manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to take care of `custom_forms_departments`.

Way: Create 2 copies of `custom_forms_departments` (c1 and c2). You'll want to JOIN them, based on (`c1.department_id = c2.department_id`) -simple, and (`c1.enduser_to_department = c2.department_to_enduser`) - because you want to get only rows that have both 'Y' in them (will filter the 'Y' in the WHEN, but for now, you'll get any rows that have same value in both columns). Second, use the WHEN to filter only 'Y'.

```
SELECT 
    custom_forms_departments.department_id
FROM
    custom_forms_departments c1
        INNER JOIN
    custom_forms_departments c2 ON c1.department_id = c2.department_id
        AND c1.enduser_to_department = c2.department_to_enduser
WHERE
    c1.enduser_to_department = 'Y'
GROUP BY
    c1.department_id 
;
```

Now we've got the "complicated" staff, lets gather all together and add the `departments` columns:

```
SELECT 
    departments.department_id, departments.department
FROM
    departments
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        custom_forms_departments.department_id
    FROM
        custom_forms_departments c1
    INNER JOIN custom_forms_departments c2 ON c1.department_id = c2.department_id
        AND c1.enduser_to_department = c2.department_to_enduser
    WHERE
        c1.enduser_to_department = 'Y'
    GROUP BY
        c1.department_id) c3 ON departments.department_id = c3.department_id
;
```

Comment: Thanks Captain Crunch **`:)`**

Comment: I also want to join it with departments table to fetch the department name. Could you please update query more to get exact result. Please..

Comment: @patrik: added that part, see answer

Comment: Plus one for Correct  answer!

Comment: @jQuery.PHP: thnx. @patrik: notice i'm using only 1 condition in WHERE, and 1 GROUP BY (i'm figuring that `departments.department_id` is your primary key, so no need to group that one), which is more efficient. also, joining and filtering in the `inner query` leaves less joining for the outer one (that why i used an inner query)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query. Also always use explicit `JOIN`

```
SELECT d.department_id, d.department 
FROM custom_forms_departments AS cfd
INNER JOIN departments AS d ON d.department_id = cfd.department_id
AND (cfd.enduser_to_department = 'Y' OR cfd.department_to_enduser = 'Y')
GROUP BY d.department_id, d.department 
ORDER BY d.department_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id as department_id, department from departments WHERE id IN 
(
SELECT DISTINCT(departament_id) FROM custom_forms_departments WHERE enduser_to_department = 'Y' OR department_to_enduser = 'Y'
)
```